# locally compact, Hausdorff, second-countable $\Rightarrow$ paracompact

Tags: general-topology

I'm digging into a proof given by Frank W. Warner:

[image]

I wonder why Warner claims that $\overline{G_i}$ is compact. One way to show this is to find a compact set that contains $G_i$. Hence, $\overline{G_i}$ will be contained in this compact set. The result then follows. But how do we find such compact set? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about the display "$\overline{G_i}$ is compact" or the argument that each of the $G_i$ that is subsequently constructed has a compact closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why Warner claims that $\overline{G_i}$ is compact.

By the definition each $G_i$ is a union of some finite subcollection of $\{U_k\}$. And each $U_k$ is relatively compact, again by the definition.

And so the conclusion follows from two facts:

1. [union of closures is closure of union for finite collections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168592/closure-of-finite-unions)
2. [finite union of compact subsets is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973340/prove-that-finite-unions-of-compact-sets-are-compact).

Comment: $U_k$ cannot be compact since in a Hausdorff space, a compact set must be closed.

Comment: @Steve $U$ is *relatively* compact, meaning it has compact closure. It wasn’t said $U$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

A basic fact (pun intended) is that a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ has a base $\mathcal{B}$ such that all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ have compact closures.

Then $X$ being second countable implies that every base for $X$ can be thinned out to (has a subcollection that is)  a countable base.

These two facts imply the first line of the proof. The rest just uses that closures commute with finite unions and finite unions of compact sets are compact.